# How to find a median from a list of values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I exported a CSV file to Python and organized it into lists.
I need to print the 'Median' carat for the 'Premium' category (yellow marked).

Here is my code:

```
diamonds_file = open('diamonds.csv', 'r')
lines = diamonds_file.readlines()
table=[]
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i]=lines[i].replace('\n', '')
    splitted_line=lines[i].split(',')
    print(splitted_line)
```

Please see the attached output of this code above:

[image]

Comment: I didn't understand what problem you were having when trying to do this. Please elaborate.

Comment: Typically, in order to find the median value of a list, sort the list and take the middle index.

Comment: I don't know how to find the **median carat** of **premium** type diamonds

Comment: Do you know how to find the premium type diamonds to begin with?

Comment: No. I stuck here

Comment: Then you have asked a question that is one step (or more) ahead.

Comment: Images of data are not useful.  Paste the *text* of diamonds.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can use external librares.

```
import statistics
diamonds_file = open('diamonds.csv', 'r')
lines = diamonds_file.readlines()
table=[]
values=[]
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i]=lines[i].replace('\n', '')
    splitted_line=lines[i].split(',')
    if splitted_line[1] == '"Premium"':   
        values.append(float(splitted_line[0]))
print(statistics.median(values))
```

Whitout external lib.

```
diamonds_file = open('diamonds.csv', 'r')
lines = diamonds_file.readlines()
table=[]
values=[]
n = 0
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i]=lines[i].replace('\n', '')
    splitted_line=lines[i].split(',')
    if splitted_line[1] == '"Premium"':   
        values.append(float(splitted_line[0]))
        n += 1
print(sum(values)/n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv into pandas...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('diamonds.csv')
```

If the csv has no headers then select columns by index number (this is what I do below) or rename columns...and continue.

```
df_Premium = df[df[1] == 'Premium']
stats = df_Premium.describe()
display(stats)
```

The median will be in the stats printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Pandas library, it is a Data Analysis Library.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("diamonds.csv")
```

And you can see the uniform table stored into a dataframe `df`.
Now you want **median** from a specific metric

```
df.groupby('cut').median()
```

Which shows all numerical metric's median.
Now, indicate specific column that you need:

```
df.groupby('cut').median()['cart']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def premiummedian(splitted_line):
    premium_carat=[]
    n=0
    for line in splitted_line:
        if line[1]=="Premium":
            premium_carat.append(float(line[0]))
            n+=1
    # not sure if you have to sort for median. If yes then
    #remove comment from the line below this
    premium_carat.sort()
    if n%2==0:# if length is even then return the middle element
        return premium_carat[n//2]
    else:#if length is odd then return the avg of 2 elements at the middle
        return (premium_carat[n//2]+premium_carat[(n//2)+1])/2
```

Comment: I copy pasted from vscode it doesn't let me post correctly.

Comment: Yes it does, you just have to use the editor correctly. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @RitikAttri- I tried to run your code but it has no output. Also, I don't need to sort for the median. I need to find the median for the premium category of cuts. Also, my CSV file contains headers:  carat, cut, color,clarity

Comment: I don't understand because I used the same list in your output image and it seems to work. Please make sure you are sending the splitted_lines in the functions and you are returning what the function returns not just call it and leave it at that :) And I just changed the type Im sorry I completely missed the numbers are a string.